# Работа функции to_date()

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

В рамках проекта требовалось читать csv файл и сохранять поля в таблицу (используется Oracle DB 11g), одно из полей имело тип DATE.

Для конвертации использовалась функция `to_date([значение],'DD.MM.YYYY')`.

Во время тестирования выяснилось, что при подаче на вход даты в формате DD.MM.YY функция работает некорректно (хотя в книге Прайса "*Oracle Database 11g SQL. Операторы SQL и программы PL/SQ*L" указано, что в таких случаях субд автоматически применяет шаблон 'DD.MM.YY', где век определяется настройками сервера ).
Пример:

```
select to_date('13.11.13','DD.MM.YYYY') from dual; -- возвращает 13.11.0013 вместо 13.11.2013
```

Если использовать `to_date('13.11.13','DD.MM.YY')` то все ок.

Подскажите причину, по которой вместо настроек сервера, используется 00.

Comment: Для 'DD.MM.YYYY' надо передавать строку вида '13.11.2013', так как вы сами указываете для года 4 цифра в формате.

Comment: Я в курсе, меня интересует причина по которой, Oracle воспринимает 
значение вида DD.MM.YY как DD.MM.00YY при использовании маски 'DD.MM.YYYY'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> меня интересует причина по которой, Oracle воспринимает значение вида DD.MM.YY как DD.MM.00YY при использовании маски 'DD.MM.YYYY'.

Маска YYYY интерпретируется согласно стандарта [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). В стандарте сказано:

> Each date and time value has a fixed number of digits that must be padded with leading zeros.

То есть, значение года должно добиваться нулями до 4-х знаков. Никакого игнорирования настроек сервера здесь нет.

Если необходимо интерпретировать дату `13.11.13` как 2013 год, используйте маску `DD.MM.RR` или `DD.MM.RRRR`.

Comment: Значит в книге ошибка, спасибо большое за информацию. Думаю использовать CAST без маски, чтобы правильно интерпретировать оба варианта.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте вот так

```
select to_date('13.11.13','DD.MM.RR') from dual
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00215

Тест http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c0be1c/5721